# ObjectParameter not getting the output value from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, webforms

In my application (VS2015, C#, WebForm), I had the following code that used to work totally fine before (both locally and on production server) but now I'm getting errors:

Stored procedure to insert an item:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure_Item_Insert]
    @ItemText VARCHAR(250),
    @InsertedID INT OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Item] ([ItemText])
    VALUES (@ItemText  -- ItemText - varchar(250)
           );

    SET @InsertedID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT @InsertedID AS InsertedID;
```

Repository code:

```
public int InsertItem(string itemText)
{
        ObjectParameter InsertedId = new ObjectParameter("InsertedID", -1);

        _db.StoredProcedure_Item_insert(feeText, InsertedId);

        return (int)InsertedId.Value;
}
```

Function import for this stored procedure in the `.edmx` file

```
Returns a Collection Of Scalars: Int32
```

And when I click the `Get Column Information button`, I get

```
Name: InsertedID
EDM Type: Int32
Db Type: int
Nullable: true
```

The only change made I can think of is that my machine was upgraded to Windows 10 so I had to reinstall VS2015.

What I've tried/found:

- `InsertedId.Value` is always -1
- The error message is in 'InsertedId` --> 'MappableType' --> 'DeclaringMethod'
- The error in `DeclaringMethod` says

  > ((System.RuntimeType)InsertedId.MappableType).DeclaringMethod threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.InvalidOperationException}
- `DeclaringMethod.Message` says

  > Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.
- Tried `OUT` and `OUTPUT` in the stored procedure
- Tried `SELECT @InsertedID` and `RETURN @InsertedID`
- Tried `new ObjectParameter("InsertedID", typeof(Int32))` instead of `-1` for the second parameter

I've been trying to figure out what is going on for so many hours now but I'm totally stuck...

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469295/retrieve-stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-entity-framework-always-null)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it makes sense that it was complaining that the result returned from the stored procedure was a result set, but I still don't know why it used to work... anyhow changing the code as follows did the trick.

Changed from:

```
    public int InsertItem(string itemText)
        {
            ObjectParameter InsertedId = new ObjectParameter("InsertedID", -1);
            _db.usp_Fee_insert(itemText, InsertedId);
            return (int)InsertedId.Value;
        }
```

To this:

```
public int InsertItem(string itemText)
    {
        ObjectParameter InsertedId = new ObjectParameter("InsertedID", -1);
        var result = _db.usp_Fee_insert(itemText, InsertedId);
        return (int)InsertedId.Value;
    }
```